# unable to upgrade TLS protocol to its latest TLSv1.3 in nginx server

Tags: nginx, openssl, tls1.3

I want to upgrade my TLS protocol to TLSv1.3 for which the requirement is nginx version should be above 1.15 and OpenSSL version is 1.1.1,
so I have upgraded my OpenSSL and Nginx to the latest, and it shows the newest version when I'm checking it on my VM(ubuntu16.04) with the command line. but when I'm trying the command **nginx -V** it still shows the OpenSSL older version.
also I have configure the `ssl_protocol TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3` and `ssl_cipher`. in nginx.conf.

can someone guide me here, what step should I take to configure the OpenSSL latest version with nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fully remove Nginx and install it from Nginx repo
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/